# timer doesn't dispose when I leave the page

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, dispose

I call my timer on initState every 10 seconds, but it doesn't dispose when I leave the page.

```
_timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => _onRefresh());
 _timer = Timer.periodic(
    Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => _onRefreshIniciados());
```

I tried these two:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

The method dispose is called but it still keeps getting called every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating two instances of `Timer`, but only calling `cancel` on one of them.

```
_timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => _onRefresh());
// _timer references ^ this object

_timer = Timer.periodic(
    Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => _onRefreshIniciados());
// _timer now references ^ object
```

In other words, after your second instantiation, your `_timer` variable only 'remembers' the second `Timer` instance. So when you're calling `cancel()` you're only cancelling the second `Timer`, while the first one remains active.

To fix this, declare two variables (`_timer1`, `_timer2`) and then cancel each of them:

```
_timer1 = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => _onRefresh());
_timer2 = Timer.periodic(
    Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => _onRefreshIniciados());

// ......

@override
  void dispose() {
    _timer1.cancel();
    _timer2.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use deactevat:

```
    @override
       void deactivate() {
       _timer!.cancel();
       _timer = null;
       super.deactivate();
```